# ASP.NET Web API - GET request with multiple arguments

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What I'm trying to do is to have an api request like /api/calculator?**1**=7.00&**2**=9.99&**3**=5.50&**4**=45.76 etc. How my controller can grab the request data? The keys/codes of the query string are ints between 1 and 1000. In the query string they can be **some** of the 1000 codes, not necessarily all of them. The value part is doubles.

The one way I think would work is if I create a model object (ex `StupidObject`) with 1000 properties (should use properties named like p1, p2,..p1000 for codes now, as ints are not an allowed property name), decorated with `ModelBinder`. Then for the controller I could have something like `GetCalcResult(StupidObject obj){...}` But that doesn't seem like an elegant solution :)

I tried controllers like `GetCalcResult([FromURI]Dictionary<int, double> dict){...}` but dict is always null. Also without the `[FromURI]` I get an error. Also tried `List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>` as controller parameter with the same results.

Could anyone point me at the right direction or give me an working example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to avoid trying to pass the values in as a parameter and simply do

```
  var queryValues = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
```

in your action method.  QueryValues will be NameValueCollection that you can iterate over to get access to your query parameters.

If you really want to use a parameter, having a parameter of type [FromUri]FormDataCollection might work.

Comment: Thanks! I used `var queryValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);`, as there was no ParseQueryString on RequestUri. Am I doing something wrong? Using the RC version.

Comment: ParseQueryString  is an extension method defined in System.Net.Http so you'd need a using System.Net.Http;