# Decoding Querystring

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this url-link : `http://localhost:50201/CastingForms/CastingList.aspx?name=&lt;a&gt;`.

How can I get parameter `name`.

For now I use this code `sname = Request.QueryString["name"];`

But it returns `""`(empty result).

I used `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode name.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what version of Net. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944358/how-to-get-query-string-variables-in-mvc-4s-request) is a possible solution.

```
  var queryValues = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
```

Then just access query values like a Dictionary collection.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect new url; I did not encode the html tag. I encode on other page. I transfer as string (`http://localhost:50201/CastingForms/CastingList.aspx?name=<a>`)

I make some changes in web-config file.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="214748364" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false">
```